# How can I determine if a block is occupied in Linux through an ioctl call?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver, ioctl

In Linux, we can call the FIBMAP() ioctl to determine which blocks a file occupies within a file system.

What I am curious about is- how can I determine if any random block is occupied with a file (or any data). Is there an ioctl to do this as well, or do I have to simply `lseek` to the block and see if there has been data written to it or not? If there's a simple ioctl call to determine if a block is occupied - that would be ideal.

Comment: For ext[234] filesystems, you can look at the [C source code](https://fossies.org/dox/e2fsprogs-1.43.4/icheck_8c_source.html) for the `icheck` command in `debugfs` to see how it traverses the raw filesystem.

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you.